# jquerymobile datepicker wrapper in listview

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker

Please see:
http://jsbin.com/xebaxiya/3/edit

Pop up works in first listview, but after clicking "Add Date" I can't see how to get the popup to work on the subsequent listviews.

Any advice?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code which adds the dynamic datepicker, remove the class="hasDatepicker" from the content string and then after appending the elements, call the datepicker() function on the new input to initialize the widget:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    nextId++;
    if (nextId<21) {
        var content = '<li class="ui-field-contain"><label for="datechosen' + nextId + '">Date ' + nextId + '</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" id="datechosen' + nextId + '" name="datechosen' + nextId + '" data-role="date" placeholder="Pop up doesnt work :( " readonly="readonly"   /></div></li>';
        $( "#set" ).append( content ).listview( "refresh" );
        $("#datechosen"  + nextId).datepicker();
    }
});
```

> Here is your updated **[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xebaxiya/6/)**

Comment: Hiya, I know this is an old question and I've appreciated your solution.  The datepicker isn't styled. And I have the extra `code`<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">`code` slipped in before the input tag.  Is there a way of sorting that? Refreshing the theme/attributes of the input? Many thanks

Comment: @devsie, seems arschmitz's demo also has no styling... you could use the  jQueryUI theme: http://jsbin.com/refamovoce/2/edit

Comment: Hello & thank you I appreciate your time.  That might be an option.  But on the working version on the site the first pop up is styled.    I note that on the first datepicker popup the id=ui-datepicker-div is assigned a class of ui-body-a and the <th> are automatically assigned a class="ui-bar-a". Yet this doesn't occur on the subsequent datepicker popups.   Also, if you remove the code forcing in class=ui-input-text that doesn't get styled either.  See [link](http://jsbin.com/kuboduyeku/1/edit?html,output)